# やっぱりここって construction, meaning

Tags: translation, particle-って

A and B have ended up in past, but maybe sure yet, although they have seen people that look like the younger versions of people they know. We pick back up with them with A saying this and B responding.

> A: B。 やっぱりここって過去の世界？
>
> B: うう……そう思うしかないのかも……

What's confusing for me is the entire やっぱりここって construction. って is most obvious the quoting bit. With ここ I guess it's saying that here/now is the past. A is wondering if they really are in the past. What does やっぱり then do? This is my current tentative translation.

> A: B. You still think we are in the past?
>
> B: Ughh…we might have no other choice but to assume that…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

やっぱり in this kind of context can be understood "I guess it's really true".

A: I guess we're really in the past?

b: mm .. it seems like there's no other explanation

Answer (score 1):

In this case,
You are in the past. At first, you cannot understand what happened.
You try to understand and consider the situation.
Then, you suspect "Here is the past world!?", but you also may say "It can't be..." You still doubt.
However, you find things which make you believe the situation and you will say "やっぱり we're really in the past!?"
B doesn't want to believe it, but B also does not have any other thought.

We use やっぱり when we want to show we already knew or guessed that before.
We did know or guess that, but most of us tend to not say clearly if we were not sure.
Guess but not speak.
If we became sure or someone says the same thought/guess, we say やっぱり to show we already guessed the same thing.
I think this is kind of japanese culuture..